Show that $M_n(P) $ is a prime ideal of $M_n(R) $.

Let $R$ be a ring and $P$ be a prime ideals of $R$. Then $M_n(P) $ is a prime ideal of $M_n(R) $.

One proof of this I know is by using the fact that any ideal of $M_n(R) $ is of the form $M_n(I) $, where $I$ is some ideal of $R$. Is there any other proof of the same without using the characterization of ideals in $M_n(R) $.

What is $M_n(P)$? Can you clarify your notation? Edit: Matrices with values in your ring, I suppose?

Why not use the characterization? It is a fundamental and rather easily proved fact.


Is there any other proof of the same without using the characterization of ideals in $_()$.

You could say that because $R/P$ is a prime ring, and that because being a prime ring is Morita invariant, the ring
$M_n(R/P)\cong M_n(R)/M_n(P)$ is prime.  Hence you would then also know $M_n(P)$ is a prime ideal of $M_n(R)$.
